# SPARQL - how to do a join operation

Tags: sparql, rdf, semantic-web

I have a model, where I have 3 classes:

1. SR - `<http://data.sample.com/vocab/StudentRecord>`
2. HCVR - `<http://data.sample.com/vocab/HealthCenterVisitRecord>`
3. CR - `<http://data.sample.com/vocab/ClassRoom>`

`StudentRecord` has a property `classRoom`.

`HealthCenterVisitRecord` has a property `studentRecord`.

Given a particular `ClassRoom` URI, how do I find all the `StudentRecord`s, who are properties of `HealthCenterVisitRecord`s.

Query that I tried (The initial part of the query fetches the student belonging to a `ClassRoom`, but the second part is screwed up and I know it):

```
SELECT ?hcvr
WHERE {
  ?sr rdf:type <http://data.sample.com/vocab/StudentRecord>.
  ?sr <http://data.sample.com/vocab/classRoom> <http://data.sample.com/resource/ClassRoom/1156>.
  ?sr <http://data.sample.com/vocab/healthCentreVisitRecord> ?hcvr.
}
```

Another query I tried:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?sr WHERE {
  {
  ?sr rdf:type <http://data.sample.com/vocab/StudentRecord>.
  ?sr <http://data.latize.com/vocab/classRoom> <http://data.latize.com/resource/ClassRoom/1156>.
  }
UNION
  { 
        ?hcvr rdf:type <http://data.sample.com/vocab/HealthCentreVisitRecord>.
        ?hcvr <http://data.sample.com/vocab/studentRecord> ?sr.
    }
}
LIMIT 1000
```

Comment: Broken links. please provide the code in your question

Comment: Those are not links, but RDF data types.
I'm not sure of the SPARQL query to be written, thus the questions.

Comment: ok understood; they are just seen as links on SO

Comment: Try `SELECT ?hcvr ?sr WHERE {?sr <http://data.sample.com/vocab/classRoom> <http://data.sample.com/resource/ClassRoom/1156>. ?hcvr <http://data.sample.com/vocab/StudentRecord> ?sr. }`. Are you sure that you have a class and a property with the same name (`StudentRecord`)?

Comment: @StanislavKralin minor typo in your query, the properties start with lower case. Indeed the query itself is correct.

Comment: @manishKungwani Next time, just take a sheet of paper and draw the schema graph: `HCVR --classRoom--> CR --studentRecord--> SR` . Then building query patterns should be straightforward. Indeed StanislavKralin showed the solution this time in his comment

Comment: @manishKungwani, thus, your query should be like this (thanks to AKSW): `SELECT ?hcvr ?sr WHERE {?sr <http://data.sample.com/vocab/classRoom> <http://data.sample.com/resource/ClassRoom/1156>. ?hcvr <http://data.sample.com/vocab/studentRecord> ?sr. }`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, here is the query:

```
SELECT ?hcvr
WHERE {
  ?sr rdf:type <http://data.sample.com/vocab/StudentRecord>.
  ?sr <http://data.sample.com/vocab/classRoom> <http://data.sample.com/resource/ClassRoom/1156>.
  ?hcvr rdf:type <http://data.sample.com/vocab/healthCentreVisitRecord>.
  ?hcvr <http://data.sample.com/vocab/studentRecord> ?sr.
}
```